# YouTube API v3 Grab Duration

Tags: php, youtube-api

I have a script that grabs the duration of a Youtube video.

It was working fine but for some reason it now gets the following error:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=Prt-G4cPIn4&key=[API_KEY]):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Here's the code:

```
$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$video_id&key=$apikey");

    $duration = json_decode($dur, true);
    foreach ($duration['items'] as $vidTime) {
    $vTime = new DateInterval($vidTime['contentDetails']['duration']);
    }

    $vid_time = $vTime->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

I have no idea why this would stop working all of a sudden.

Comment: Works with my key, so verify your key is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

The var $apikey is wrong "[API_KEY]", solve this first and go appear other error, comming by the headers and CORS